# ReactJS select value from json array

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to get some data from my api and then select that data and send it to the other api, but I can't figure it out how to select the data.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'


class Testas extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
    }
}


componentDidMount() {

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ',''
        
    };
      fetch(`https://spiceworks/api/printserver/printers`,{ headers }
      )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {  
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: json.printers,
        }) 
      });
     
   
}
  render() {

    const { items } = this.state
    const type = ['test', 'python', 'web', 'all']
    const amount = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   
    return (
        <div className="content">
        <form>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm">
          <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
          <h3 className="card-title">Printer Test</h3>
          <Dropdown className="drop" options={this.state.items}  placeholder="Pasirinkti printerį" /> 
          <Dropdown className="drop2" options={type}  placeholder="Būdas" /> 
          <Dropdown className="drop2" options={amount}  placeholder="Kiekis" /> 
          <a href={`https://spiceworks/api/${items}/test`} className="btn ">Test</a>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
    }
  }

export default Testas
```

the data I recieve from api looks like this

```
{
"printers": [
    "ZEB-SOFA15",
    "ZEB-120",
    "GDX-SOFUZ4",]}
```

i tried with e value onchange code but then I always get error that data.map is not a function.

Comment: where is the ```.map()``` in your code ?

Comment: Please confirm that you would like to change the a href so that it includes the currently selected printer from the select element

Comment: so how should I use map in this code? I tried with it but it did not work and i posted the code which atm works and gets the data to render
About the href I will later on change it to correspond to the selected value of printer

Comment: Your `Dropdown` component supports parameter `onChange`. This is being executed whenever you selected some other value from your dropdown and passes the newly selected value to whatever method you provide as a parameter. Here is a simple example i created: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-currying-r7779?file=/src/App.js:974-982

Comment: Additionally, if you wanna execute an api call whenever you select something, would recommend saving the value in a state, then with the use of `useEffect` to execute the call when the value changes. This would allow you to lock your dropdown whenever value has been selected so the user can not spam selections and make loads of api calls and unlock only when the api has been fully executed.